# SwiftUI Swipe Actions Note Working Correctly

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I’m working on this shopping list and basically I have a list of tile views that have swipe actions.

The bought and delete actions work perfectly, but I am unable to get the edit button to work. The edit button pulls up a form already filled with the item’s information so you can edit it.

The code for the button works, when I make the tile itself a button and tap the tile the edit form comes up.

Is there a limit to swipe actions that limit you pulling up a form in a swipe action? Here is the code for the list. Thanks! (Program is coded using swift ui and swift)

```
ForEach(Item) { madeItem in
    FoodListTileView(foodItem: madeItem)
        .swipeActions(edge: .leading) {
            Button {
                madeItem.justBought()
                FoodDataController.shared.saveItem(madeItem: madeItem)
            } label: {
                Label("Just Bought", systemImage: "checkmark.square")
            }
            .tint(.green)
        }
        .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
            Button { FoodDataController.shared.deleteItem(madeItem: madeItem)} label : {
                Label("Delete", systemImage:"trash")
            }
            .tint(.red)

            Button(action: {showingCreateView = true})  {

                Label("Edit", systemImage: "pencil.circle")

            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingCreateView) {
                AddItemView(Item: madeItem)
            }
            .tint(.orange)
        }
    }
}
.listStyle(.plain)
```

Comment: Move your sheet from Button to the end of ForEach and use ```sheet(item``` to pass data.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps...I had a simultaneous drag gesture, when i removed it everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

@Raja is absolutely right. The `.sheet` inside `swipeAction` doesn't work, it has to be outside. Better even outside of the `ForEach`, as otherwise it will always only show the last value of the forEach.

If it's outside the ForEach, you have to use a different way to let `sheet` know which data to display: `.sheet(item:)` which is the better alternative in most cases anyway. For that go from `@State var showingCreateView: Bool` to something like `@State var editingItem: Item?` where Item should be your items Class. And in the button action, give it the current item value.

Here is the amended code:

```
// test item struct
struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    // test data
    @State private var items = [
        Item(name: "Butter"),
        Item(name: "Honey"),
        Item(name: "Bread"),
        Item(name: "Milk"),
        Item(name: "Ham")
    ]
    
    @State private var editingItem: Item? // replace Item with your item type
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { madeItem in
                Text(madeItem.name)
                
                    .swipeActions(edge: .leading){
                        Button {
                        } label: {
                            Label("Just Bought", systemImage: "checkmark.square")
                        }
                        .tint(.green)
                    }
                
                    .swipeActions(edge: .trailing){
                        Button {
                        } label : {
                            Label("Delete", systemImage:"trash")
                        }
                        .tint(.red)
                        
                        Button {
                            editingItem = madeItem // setting editingItem (anything else but nil) brings up the sheet 
                        } label: {
                            Label("Edit", systemImage: "pencil.circle")
                        }
                        .tint(.orange)
                    }
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $editingItem) { item in  // change to item: init here
            Text("Edit: \(item.name)")
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
    }
}
```

[image]